# ffmpeg start timecode frame misinterpretation when reinterlacing 50p to 50i

Tags: ffmpeg, video

we try to convert 50p files to 50i using this command:

ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 120M -q 1 -flags +ildct -vf  "fps=50,format=yuv422p,scale=1920:1080,interlace,fieldorder=tff" "coded%%~ni_1080i50.mov"

the resulting file has the same duration and starting hours minutes and seconds.
But the frames number of the starting timecode ist doubled.
e.g.

original: 10:05:03:12
encoded:  10:05:03:24

or
original: 10:05:03:20
encoded:  10:05:04:15

It is definetly an issue with the -vf "interlace" filter. When I remove this and encode the file again to 1080p50 the timecode is correct.

I guess this is a misinterpretation. Maybe a *2 instead of /2 in the code? In my opinion the right correspondending timecodes should be:

`50p: 00 01 02 03 04 05 ... 48 49`

`50i: 00 00 01 00 02 00 ... 24 24`

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Kind Regards
Bjoern

Comment: Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org with full command and log.

Comment: Hi Gyan, I will give it a try, thank you.